# Unique associative array with count

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, unique, associative

Having trouble not getting the way to achieve the following with the array. I intend to reduce the array to unique values, although, getting the total count for each of the unique elements. For instance, get a final array like:

`var data = [14:"A",5:"IMG",2:"SPAN"]`

which corresponds to the total of items in each unique tag, associated with the tag itself. 
My original sample array is the following:

`var data = ["A", "A","A","IMG","IMG","A","A","IMG","A","A","IMG","A","A","IMG","IMG","A","A","A","A","A","SPAN","SPAN"]`

Comment: You could sort the original array (or a deep copy of it) and then count the doubles. Btw. there are 14 `A`s and 6 `IMG`s in your example...

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: Thanks. But the problems is indeed that, building the new associative  array with the counts associated with the tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get

```
var data = [14:"A",5:"IMG",2:"SPAN"]
```

because that is not valid JavaScript. Also, if the count would end up being similar for different tags, you would get duplicate keys. Turn the key/values around, and use JavaScript object:

```
var reduced = {A: 14, IMG: 6, SPAN: 2};
```

In Ecmascript 5:

```
var data = ["A","A","A","IMG","IMG","A","A","IMG","A","A","IMG","A","A","IMG","IMG","A","A","A","A","A","SPAN","SPAN"]; 

var reduced = data.reduce(function (result, item) {
    result[item] = (result.hasOwnProperty(item) ? result[item] : 0) + 1; 
    return result; 
}, {}); 

console.log(reduced); // Object {A: 14, IMG: 6, SPAN: 2}
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cqJw6/)

If you need to support browsers without "reduce", you can find reduce in [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/)

```
var reduced = _.reduce(data, function (result, item) {
    result[item] = (result.hasOwnProperty(item) ? result[item] : 0) + 1; 
    return result; 
}, {});
```

jsFiddle with underscore [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cqJw6/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and help. I do prefer the Ecmascript 5 option as it returns an object, which allows more flexibility in its usage. For browsers that don't support reduce... WC - who cares ;) :) thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = ["A", "A", "A", "IMG", "IMG", "A", "A", "IMG", "A", "A", "IMG", "A", "A", "IMG", "IMG", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "SPAN", "SPAN"];
var temp = [];
$.each(data,function(i,v){
 if ($.inArray(v, temp) == -1) temp.push(data[i]);
});
var count = [];
var c = 0;
$.each(temp,function(i,v){
  $.each(data,function (index, val) {
    if (v == val) c++;
   });
   count.push(c);
   c = 0;
});
var obj = {};
for (var i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
  obj[temp[i]] = count[i]
 }
 console.log(obj); //Object { A=14, IMG=6, SPAN=2}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aqPb2/2/

Comment: thanks for the help. I prefer the below approach which seems to be more lightweight. Thanks!